# Neo4j as a file in Python

Tags: database, neo4j, graph-databases

I want to use Neo4j database to store data in my Python script. However I do not want to start Neo4j before I run this script. How (if it is possible) to use Neo4j database from Python code as a file (without connection by the network).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean writing a python script that reads neo4j content from the neo4j files on the filesystem, I'd say NO, don't go this way unless you have plenty of time to spend (but code is on github).

Just start the server in embedded mode in a Java class.

See http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/#tutorials-java-embedded

Comment: Are exist another graph databases which allow to using database from file system without running external process?